# How to make lightslider jquery plugin work in a reactjs component?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

This is my code on rendering the lightslider gallery. My problem is that the jquery gallery does not display correctly. It only renders the photos but without the styles. I have read about componentDidMount mounting before render begins. The markup on the `vertical` list is the way on how to use the lightslider gallery.

What do you seem is the problem? How can we use a jquery plugin and then render it via reactjs component?

```
render(){
    const photodata = this.props.gallery;
    const datax = photodata.data;

    return(
        <div>
            {datax.map(function(object,i){
                let standardprops = object.properties;
                let photos = standardprops.Photos;

                {
                    return(
                        object.properties.Photos.map(function(fields){
                            let photo = fields.photos;
                            let thumb = fields.thumbnail;

                            return (
                                <ul id="vertical">
                                    <li key={fields.i} data-thumb={thumb} data-src={photo}>
                                        <img src={photo} className="img-responsive" />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            )
                        })
                    )
                }

            })}    
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading docs about componentDidMount, I have come up with this solution. I also got it from the egghead site which is this: https://egghead.io/lessons/react-using-react-with-the-fullcalendar-jquery-plugin

```
componentDidMount(){

    const {vertical} = this.refs;  

    $(vertical).lightSlider({
        gallery:true,
        item:1,
        slideMargin:0,
        speed:500,
        auto:false,
        loop:true,
        adaptiveHeight:true,
        vertical:true,
        verticalHeight:600,
        vThumbWidth:220,
        thumbItem:4,
        thumbMargin:5,
        onSliderLoad: function(el) {
            el.lightGallery({
                selector: '.vertical .lslide'
            });
        },
        responsive : [
            {
                breakpoint:1025,
                settings: {
                    item:1,
                    slideMove:1,
                    gallery:true,
                    thumbItem:8,
                    vThumbWidth:120
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint:769,
                settings: {
                    item:1,
                    slideMove:1,
                    gallery:true,
                    thumbItem:8,
                    vThumbWidth:100,
                    verticalHeight:450
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint:737,
                settings: {
                    item:1,
                    slideMove:1,
                    gallery:false,
                    thumbItem:0,
                  }
            },
            {
                breakpoint:668,
                settings: {
                    item:1,
                    slideMove:1,
                    gallery:false,
                    thumbItem:0,
                  }
            },
            {
                breakpoint:641,
                settings: {
                    item:1,
                    slideMove:1,
                    gallery:false,
                    thumbItem:0,
                  }
            },
            {
                breakpoint:480,
                settings: {
                    item:1,
                    slideMove:1,
                    gallery:false,
                    thumbItem:0,
                }
            }
        ]   
    });
}
```

The render is also now different. Instead of putting the ul inside the map. I put it outside with the `refs` to `vertical`

```
render(){
const photodata = this.props.gallery;
const datax = photodata.data;

return(
    <div>
        <ul ref="vertical">
        {datax.map(function(object,i){
            let standardprops = object.properties;
            let photos = standardprops.Photos;

            {
                return(
                    object.properties.Photos.map(function(fields){
                        let photo = fields.photos;
                        let thumb = fields.thumbnail;

                        return (

                                <li key={fields.i} data-thumb={thumb} data-src={photo}>
                                    <img src={photo} className="img-responsive" />
                                </li>

                        )
                    })
                )
            }

        })}
        </ul>   
    </div>
)}
```